# Change background color of the button in UITableViewCell based on selection

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//Where we configure the cell in each row

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


self.myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.myButton.tag = 5;
self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(190.0f, 5.0f, 70.0f, 25.0f);
self.myButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.myButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
self.myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.myButton setTitle:@"Set Active" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview: self.myButton];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

}

-(void) myButton:(id)sender{
[sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Assume, there 3 rows in the tableview section. I have the button in 3 rows.
At the first instance, the button in the first row should have red color and the other 2 rows should have gray color.
If I select the button in the 2nd row, then the button in the 2nd row should be red and the other 2 gray and so on. I haven't figured out a way to do it. Any suggestions?

I am able to change the color of the button I have selected from cell. But at the same instance, the previously selected button and all the other buttons(except the selected button) should be default color. At a time only one button will be highlighted, and that will always be the selected button at that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right way to do this - subclass `UITableViewCell` and declare own protocol that will inform delegate in which cell button was pressed, and in the delegate - loop through all cells and set default color for all and red color for selected.
I made [demo project](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8255225/test_cell.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is set different tag for each button. Like this:

```
button.tag = indexPath.row + c;
```

when 'c' is constant.
And in you method:

```
-(void) myButton:(id)sender{
     for( int i=0; i<numberOfRowsInTable; ++i )
        [(UIButton *)[self.view viewForTag:i+c] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
     [(UIButton *)sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

But if you have 2 or more section in table this way may be not work

Comment: My problem, is how to set the unselected buttons to default color. Only the selected button should be red.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [How can I loop through UITableView's cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914183/how-can-i-loop-through-uitableviews-cells)

Loop through the cells and set the "inactive" buttons to gray.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code:

```
-(void) myButton:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"sender Tag=== %d",[sender tag]);
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor ]];

}
```

Comment: My problem, is how to set the unselected buttons to default color. Only the selected button should be red.