# Make Change in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I'm working on the `TableView`, and I have used the label on the `TableViewCell` and on the button click I want to hide the label from all cells in my table,
In the label I have set the tag:

```
label.tag = indexPath.row+1;
```

And on the button click I am using the code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array.count; i++)
{
    [[self.view viewWithTag:i+1] setHidden:YES];      
}
```

But from my code the label is hiding only from the last cell not all the others.

Comment: What is the array...show that ?

Comment: Use the delegate/datasource methods and tell the tableview to reload specific cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this with another way.

1. First you need to declare a BOOL in your class

   ```
   @property(assign,nonatomic) BOOL hideLabels;
   ```
2. Next in your button action handler method, set this **YES**
3. In your **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, check whether **hideLabels** is **YES**, if yes, the hide labels using code.

   ```
    cell.yourLabel.hidden = hideLabels;
   ```
4. Now reload the table after setting **hideLabels** as **YES**

   ```
   [self.tableView reloadData];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(id object in tableView.subviews)
    {

      if([object isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
      {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *) object;
        [[label setHidden:YES];      

      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController.h

```
BOOL isLabelHidden;
```

in  ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   isLabelHidden = FALSE;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";

    UILabel *lbl;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = nil;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

     if(isLabelHidden)
       [lbl setHidden:YES];
     else
       [lbl setHidden:NO];
}
```

in you button clicked method

```
- (void)buttonClicked
{
  isLabelHidden = TRUE;
  [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first get the reference to the `UITableViewCell` and then you can remove the labels in them.

First of all get the reference to all the cells in your tableview as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [tableView numberOfSections]; ++j)
{
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
{
    [cells addObject:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]];
}
}
```

And now iterate through those cells in cells Array to hide the label view,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < cells.count; i++)
    {
       [[[cells objectAtIndex:i] viewWithTag:i+1] setHidden:YES];      
    }
```

Source:[How can I loop through UITableView's cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914183/how-can-i-loop-through-uitableviews-cells)